# Join retrieve, all column of table A with a column from Table B

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Environment : Java, Hibernate, Oracle

I got 2 tables A and B. I did a join as follows

```
Select * from A a INNER JOIN B b ON a.if = b.reciptID WHERE <condition>
```

Here my question is how can I retrieve,

All the column of table A  with a column (b.reciptID) from table B by querying in HQL or hibernate.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*, b.reciptID FROM A a JOIN B b ON a.if = b.reciptID
```

This will give you what you ask for; you don't need a WHERE clause.  I think that what you didn't know is that you can use a table alias along with * if you only want all the values from one of the tables.